# find the closest "floored number" to a given number in a data frame column whilst dealing with ties

Tags: r

The task is to find the closest number in a column to a given number> If there are ties the smallest one number is to be chosen. This is my clumsy attempt, which seems to work but maybe some experts could help to improve this? Thanks.

```
df <- data.frame(
        x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4)
      )
number <- 2.5
df <- df %>% mutate(absolute_difference = abs(x - number)) %>% arrange(absolute_difference, x)
head(df)

result <- as.numeric(head(df$x, 1))
result
```

So given:

```
1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4
```

and:

```
2.5
```

the expected result is 2.

Comment: In your example `result` is 1, but you your expected `result` should be 2?

Comment: Do you want something like: `df$x[which.min(abs(df$x - number))]` ?

Comment: @bird the result is definitely 2

Comment: @GKi - thanks that works as well. I tried something along those lines which did not work - hence my dplyr "solution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which.min` to subset for the value of `df$x` at that postition.

```
df$x[which.min(abs(df$x - number))]
#[1] 2
```